# Error popping up when I'm opening brave browser?Fix?

Tags: authorization, brave

When I open the brave browser, a window (given below) opens up.
It doesn't really interfere with the processing of the browser.
But it is concerning why this keeps happening...

[Error On Opening Brave Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8rIc.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

after digging more into this, for me, it was the google keep extension. it repeatedly needs to be repaired in the brave extensions manager and this thread is what prompted me to try uninstalling it. https://www.reddit.com/r/brave_browser/comments/x8f7w8/extensions_not_working_in_brave_desktop_mac/

since uninstalling, on two separate systems, this no longer appears at launch. i pinned a google keep tab and that works for me.

tl;dr - google keep does not work with brave.

Comment: I can confirm your findings.  I also had the google keep extension installed on multiple PCs and this started after the most recent Brave update.  Removing the extension prevents the error.